# mssql express 2005 linked server Invalid object name

Tags: sql-server, caching, ssms, linked-server

I have created linked server using first post in this site: http://www.sqlservercentral.com/Forums/Topic340912-146-1.aspx But I cannot work on from 5. Change the Properties of the Provider MSDASQL .There is no such thing as Properties in Right Click MSDASQL. I wanted to clear cache, but there is no such thing as Edit->IntelliSense or Tools >> Options >> Text Editor >> Transact-SQL. I am using SSMS Express 2005 and connecting with windows authentication. I am trying this linked server query: select * from [MYSQLAPP].databaseName.tableName and I get Invalid object name 'MYSQLAPP.databaseName.tableName '. Dont know what to do. I am going mad after hours of search.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If someone else is struggling answer is I should use: SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(MYSQLAPP, 'SELECT * FROM databasename.tablename')